# A better database model for holding postage prices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-design

I wanted to create a `Postage_costs` table to  hold postages costs, each `postage_cost` has a name, e.g Large Item, which has different costs(standard price and express postage price)  depending on location so the `Large_Item` might look like;

```
Name: Large Item
Cost: UK:
         standard: 5
         express: 10
      Europe:
         standard:10
         express
      R.o.w:
         standard: 20
         express: 30
```

I originally had Name as a string and cost as a text field which held the serialized contents of a hash but it's become a little difficult to create new countries and their rates. I'd  prefer to keep it all in one table, so is there a better way?
I'm using rails and PostgreSQL

Comment: Use the Royal Mail's API. They offer a couple of web services, e.g.: http://www.epro.royalmail.com/WebServices/import/eproimport.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 1):

Serializing has some disadvantages. For example, you cannot create database indexes on the serialized contents in order to optimize you queries. Also, application validations are going to be a mess.

My suggestion is to just have 2 extra columns on your table. So have something like:

```
postages
  name
  country
  standard_price
  express_price
```

Answer (score 0):

Have one entry for each country.

```
name: Large Item
country: UK
standard_price: 5
express_price: 10

name: Large Item
country: Europe
standard_price: 10
express_price:

name: Large Item
country: Europe
standard_price: 20
express_price: 30
```